# A... Au... Audit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I came across two suspicious suggested edits today:

- https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/189170
- https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/189177

Looks much like audits. What happened?

Comment: Well, you two audited well. All I see is an anonymous user "vandalizing" some posts, and two reviewers rightfully rejecting those edits. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have review audits on this site. While the second one does look like the random garbage of an autogenerated edit for an audit, it's a real edit someone suggested. We do occasionally get rubbish edits like this, and more often spam edits like the first one you linked.

Like flagging posts as spam, rejecting edits as "spam or vandalism" feeds the suggester's info (IP address etc.) into the anti-spam system, making it harder for them to come back and keep wasting our time with spam edits.